# Checkbox validation - at least one selected

Tags: javascript, checkbox, validation

I have number of checkboxes and another checkbox for "Select All"

I want to check if the user has selected at least one checkbox. Need modification in javascript

```
<script language="Javascript">

function doSubmit(){
function check_checkboxes() 
{ 
checked=false;
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT'); 
for (var i = 1; i < c.length; i++) 
{ 
    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') 
    { 
    if (c[i].checked) {
    return true} 
    else {alert("Please identify what warehouses comply:");  }
        } 
    } //if I place my struts action here..its not working?
}    
document.holiDay.command.value= 'addingApp'; //My Struts action if something checked. 
document.holiDay.submit(); 
}
```

Comment: Please post the HTML for your checkboxes.

Comment: Looks like you found an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507117/merge-two-javascripts) - maybe you can accept on of these answers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var all=document.getElementById('holiDay');
```

In HTML IDs should be unique, so getElementById will only return 1 element. Perhaps you could try getElementsByTagName - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439(VS.85).aspx ?

Something like...

```
function check_checkboxes()
{
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
  {
    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox')
    {
       if (c[i].checked) {return true}
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

and change your Validate function to...

```
function Validate()
{
    if(!check_checkboxes())
    {
        alert("Please identify what warehouses comply:");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Its not working. When I click the submit button, its not even going into the loop.
[code]
<script language="Javascript">
         
function doSubmit(){
 function check_checkboxes() 
 { 
 checked=false;
 var c = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT'); 
 for (var i = 1; i < c.length; i++) 
 { 
     if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') 
     { 
       if (c[i].checked) {
        return true} 
     else {alert("Please identify what warehouses comply:");  }
      } 
    } 
 }  
 document.holiDay.command.value= 'addingApp';
 document.holiDay.submit(); 
}
[/code]

Comment: Ok, Ive added more to my original answer (see above)
(Or see Jets answer - but I think this depends on Jquery?)

Comment: I know that this is an old post, but I was looking at it and I have a quick question (more javascript syntax related I guess), when you write 'if (c[i].check){return true}', won't that break out of the for loop and not continue on with checking the rest of the checkbox array?

Comment: @de1337ed - yes it will. The requirement from the original question was to check if at least one checkbox is checked - once we have found one that is checked we don't need to continue with the loop, we just return 'true'. If however, we get through the loop without finding any checked checkboxes then we return false. yes?

Answer (score 3):

Select at least one check box using jqQery. Try the following code.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="class"]').on('change', function () {
    var getArrVal = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="class"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).toArray();

    if (getArrVal.length) {
        //execute the code
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
        alert("Select at least one column");
        return false;
    }
    ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (function() {
  for(x in $ = document.getElementsByTagName("input"))
   with($[x])
    return (type == "checkbox" ? checked == true : 0)
 })
```

Comment: Please don't use `with`, or worse, suggest its use to others.