# Merge two JavaScript scripts

Tags: javascript, function, forms, checkbox

I have two JavaScript code snippets. These perform specific task when an 'Update' button is clicked.

I would like to merge them. Any help is appreciated.

JavaScript 1: When the button is clicked, it checks if at least one checkbox is selected:

```
function doUpdate(){
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { 
        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox' && c[i].checked == true) { 
            // At least one checkbox is checked     
            document.holiDay.command.value= 'update';
            document.holiDay.submit();  
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
    // Nothing has been checked 
    alert("Please identify what warehouses comply:"); 
    return false; 
}
```

JavaScript 2: When any checkbox is checked and update button is clicked, check all of them or uncheck all of them if any checkbox is unchecked; then perform the update feature:

```
function doUpdate(){
    checked=false;
    function All (holiDay) {
        var all= document.getElementById('holiDay');
        if (checked == false){
            checked = true
        }
        else{
            checked = false
        }
        for (var i =0; i < all.elements.length; i++){ 
            all.elements[i].checked = checked;
        }
    }
    //after checked or unchecked all checkboxes then submit the form and other functionality
    document.holiDay.command.value= 'update';
    document.holiDay.submit();  
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: how do you want the script to behave for the different situations? The two actions seem to conflict a little.

Comment: Could you describe in words (just like you did for the 2 existing functions) all the things you want your new function to do?

Comment: @palswim, @Peter Ajtai: This asker does not accept answers, I wouldn't waste my time with badly formulated questions that won't ever get accepted. Perhaps a troll...

Comment: @Juan: I dont know how to accept answers..can someone show me. I dont see a green button??

Comment: There's a checkmark outline that you click and it turns green to indicate the accepted answers, this is the most important thing here at SO to help us find answers. It's right below the up/down arrow with the votes. You should ask your question more carefully, nobody can figure out what you are trying to do. Usually it's better to abstract your question out of your specific context to help us understand. Many times that will help you see the problem more clearly. Your current question looks like "can somebody do my work?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you want to do, but here's a stab at it:

```
function doUpdate(){
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox' && c[i].checked == true) {
            // At least one checkbox is checked    
            UpdateHoliday();
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Nothing has been checked
    alert("Please identify what warehouses comply:");
    return false;
}

function UpdateHoliday(){
    checked = false;
    function All (holiDay) {
        var all = document.getElementById('holiDay');
        checked = !checked;
        for (var i =0; i < all.elements.length; i++){
            all.elements[i].checked = checked;
        }
    }
    //after checked or unchecked all checkboxes then submit the form and other functionality
    document.holiDay.command.value = 'update';
    document.holiDay.submit();  
}
```

It would really help to simplify and indent your code so that we could understand it more clearly.