# Check Box Validation error

Tags: javascript

I am using below code for validating the check box

```
if(!validateForm())
    {
        alert("Please select intrested in required service");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}


function validateForm()
{
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
  {
    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox')
    {
       if (c[i].checked) {return true}document.myForm.action="thankyou-enquiry-hrservice.php"  ;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I have about 5 check boxes. If checked only 1 then it will go to thankyou-enquiry-hrservice.php. If i select multiple check boxes its not redirecting to that page instead its refreshing the current page with empty fields in website.

Comment: `!validateForm()` wrong way to check the condition...

Comment: I was referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214198/checkbox-validation-at-least-one-selected/3214260#3214260

Answer (score 0):

when you do:

```
if (c[i].checked) {return true}document.myForm.action="thankyou-enquiry-hrservice.php"
```

On the first checked ítem the function will return true and the:

```
document.myForm.action="thankyou-enquiry-hrservice.php"
```

Part wont be executed.

As for the 1 checked ítem sending you to the page you want, I'd bet that it's not the first chechbox that you're selecting. So when at least evaluate to false once, it's sending you where you want to go.

As requested a quick fix could be:

```
function validateForm()
{
  var answer = false;
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
  {
    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox')
    {
       if (c[i].checked) {
           answer = true; 
           document.myForm.action="thankyou-enquiry-hrservice.php";
       }
    }
  }
  return answer;
```

}

But without knowing anything else of your intentions for this code I can't do anything else.

Comment: Can you please suggest the re write for the code. TIA

Comment: @AmithIngalagi added the example

Comment: Its not validating for multiple checkboxes. Actually I am not pro at javascript.

Comment: @AmithIngalagi it's not validating or it's not redirecting?

Comment: Its not validating + not re-directing. So I totally changed validation system to jQuery-Validation-Engine-master. Now its working fine